# How to get the PID of a process started by /bin/su -c

Tags: linux, bash, pid

I'm writing a init.d-script for an java-app. But the java-app should be run by another user.

(The OS I'm using is Debian Squeeze.)

I already got this:

```
/bin/su - $USER - c "cd $PATH;echo $PASSWORD | $JAVA -Xmx256m -jar $PATH/app.jar -d > /dev/null" & PID=$!
/bin/su - $USER - c "echo $PID > $PIDFILE"
```

But this will of course only save the pid of the "/bin/su"-process instead of the pid of the created java-process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Echo the PID inside the commands executed by "su":

```
/bin/su - $USER -c "cd $PATH;echo $PASSWORD | \
  $JAVA -Xmx256m -jar $PATH/app.jar -d > /dev/null & echo $! > $PIDFILE"
```

Comment: I tried that, but the $PIDFILE is just empty (except for a linebreak) when using that command.

Comment: Its empty because `$!` is being evaluated by the shell running `su`, not the shell that `su` runs. If you change the `$!` to `\$!` or change the double-quotes to single-quotes it should work.